# ZF2 - Trigger MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR from View Controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I am using a Restful Controller and on certain conditions, I would like the trigger the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` and stop execution of the controller immediately after. In my `Module` class, I have attached an event listener for this but I can't find a way to trigger it from the view controller.

My `Module` code is:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
    $eventManager = $mvcEvent->getApplication()
        ->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(array(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR), array($this, 'error'));
}

public function error(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {
    echo $mvcEvent->getError();
    die();
}
```

and my Controller code is:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $mvcEvent = $this->getEvent();

    $mvcEvent->setError('test-error-code');
    $mvcEvent->getTarget()->getEventManager()->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $mvcEvent);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to trigger the event vs. throwing an exception? An exception will trigger it.

Comment: @TimKlever Yes because the exception being thrown is more generic and I want to catch it at specific times to return a different error message. If I just check the error off of the exception type, I will only get the generic error, not the specific one I really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not attaching to the Application's `sharedEventManager`. You can also use the Controller's own Event Manager to trigger the event.

Try something like this:

Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent) {

    $eventManager = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

    $eventManager->attach('Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, array($this, 'error'));
}
```

Controller

```
public function indexAction() {

    $mvcEvent = $this->getEvent();
    $mvcEvent->setError('test-error-code');

    $this->getEventManager()->trigger(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, $mvcEvent);

    return;
}
```